# Is there a data-based predictive model of what newspapers cover?

Tags: public-opinion, media

I am interested in a modern analogue to Edward Herman and Noam Chomsky’s propaganda model of media. (A modern revisitation of which can be found [here](https://monthlyreview.org/2018/01/01/the-propaganda-model-revisited/).)

It would be interesting and valuable (to me) if a system could predict what a newspaper, say the New York Times, was going to report, based on underlying model or factor analysis of how they report - perhaps with a very complex range of factors, derived using explainable AI techniques.

The point would be to undermine the media’s claim to impartiality by showing what factors are really at play in how they report (or refuting this claim, which would be equally of interest and import).

As a side note, to give only one small example, I felt that the media largely focused on negative coverage of Elon Musk’s takeover of Twitter, and there has never been any accountability or follow-up showing, perhaps, that the impression created of a company hurtling towards disaster may have been a misrepresentation or false prediction. But that is just one example of what is meant to be a broad, general tendency of mainstream newspapers.

Related sources, for reference:

A data-driven social science journal: https://www.jasss.org/JASSS.html

A company that aims to simulate social phenomena: https://forio.com/solutions/government-simulation-solutions/

Comment: There has been plenty of follow-up. The latest news stories are about Elon throwing away brand recognition by changing the name of the former bird to his favorite letter. And maybe instead of being propaganda, this coverage just reflects the fact that Twitter's revenue is down 60% from the same time last year and its income flow is negative and falling, which is a terrible position for a company of its size, maturity and recognition.

Comment: I am giving this question the benefit of the doubt by connecting the only implicit claim that media coverage choices are a tool by which political opinion is formed and controlled, and that it is therefore on topic at Politics.SE even though facially the question does not connect these dots and doesn't have an expressly political hook.

Comment: *media's claim to impartiality*??? Which media?  Many/most media has a certain viewpoint - neither CNN nor Fox are impartial.  Reuters and AP News come close but they're a special case, *aiming for precisely neutrality*.  News site with a (moderate) given viewpoint aren't necessarily a problem, news sites which don't report truthfully are.  Now, concerning Musk and Twitter, well it *has* been a dumpster fire (tho admittedly Twitter was also a financial dumpster fire before Musk took over).  Why would the news not cover it as such?

Comment: Also, Manufacturing Consent was concerned with a specific subject, Western bias  wrt US vs Soviet human rights abuses, on most mainstream US news.  It was fairly successful - if biased - within those boundaries.  MC also didn't predict, it explained.  That couldn't be generalized to *all media, all subjects*.  Might be you could ask how do magazines/websites concerned with tech cover Musk@Twitter?  But how informative/political is that?  Musk@Tesla/SpaceX generally gets better press.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to use this prediction. Are you going to have it write a bunch of predicted stories, and then expect those to match the next day's issue? Even if the predictive model is good, that seems implausible.

Comment: At best I think you could have it write stories, and then see if readers are able to distinguish them from stories actually from that newspaper, like a Turing test. But experience with LLMs like ChatGPT show that it's very easy to fool readers, superficial style issues are enough.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a politics question. It doesn't mention politics, although it does mention bias which is a separate matter. Not all bias is political - the NYT covers news from New York City more than it covers Salt Lake City but that's nothing to do with the cities' respective politics.

Answer (score 2):

Closest I can name is the citation index. It is used in academic publications as a trusted standard but there is no reason why could not be tried on the journal articles.

An article that is referenced from, mentioned in other articles has the higher citation index. As the an editor typically aims to have the cumulative citation index of the own journal higher, publishing articles that are likely to receive lots of mentioning and citing elsewhere will always be preferred. By collecting articles with high citation index you can get the unbiased training set, and then do all kinds of research, drawing conclusions what is typical for the articles that are likely to be published. The negative set can be either random or articles receiving very little external references.

For science, articles with high citation index tend to publish new observations of high importance.

Comment: The fact that this answer somewhat seems to apply to the question, and is also not political in nature, seems to point at a flaw in the question:  there isn't all that much that is political in the question.  And, FWIW, while the answer seems solid, it seems like it would be leveraging good old-fashioned *statistics*, as expected, rather than *sexy new AI* which seems a long way from Manufacturing Consent and seems trendy rather relevant, *at least in this context*.  +1 but really this was a deeply flawed question.